# gunzip redirection to /etc/: No such file or directory

Tags: gzip

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial on how to make a vpn](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04), but I am having some trouble gunzipping.

If I try to put in the code

```
sudo gunzip -c '/usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/server.conf.gz > /etc/openvpn/server.conf'
```

it responds with a

```
gzip: /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/server.conf.gz > /etc/openvpn/server.conf.gz: No such file or directory
```

What is going on?

I put the `sudo` and quotation marks because you cannot `gzip` to `etc` without it.

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://superuser.com/questions/45650/how-do-you-gunzip-a-file-and-keep-the-gz-file/45651

Comment: @JuliePelletier If I do not have the quotes, it says that the permission was denied to access /etc/openvpn/server.conf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your quotation mark is placed incorrectly.

Run it like this instead:

```
sudo gunzip -c '/usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/server.conf.gz' > '/etc/openvpn/server.conf'
```

As you had it, the whole `'/usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/server.conf.gz > /etc/openvpn/server.conf'` part was treated as single argument - and of course no file with this path exists.

Now it is split up in one quoted path argument to the `gunzip` command (`/usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/server.conf.gz'`) followed by a Bash output redirection into `'/etc/openvpn/server.conf'`.

However, as neither of the two paths in your example contains spaces or other special characters, the quotes are not necessary and could also have been omitted altogether.

---

As you say you have no write permission on file where you want to redirect the output to, you must write it like this:

```
sudo bash -c "gunzip -c '/usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/server.conf.gz' > '/etc/openvpn/server.conf'"
```

Comment: I don't know if I should make another question or not but if I do that it instead says

>bash: /etc/openvpn/server.conf: Permission denied.

Comment: Edited my answer @nimbyest